# How to send sms about my location address in android

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, sms

I am newbie in android technology. just a week before i have started learning .I am trying to send the details about my location with my registered mobile number. It is working fine just in SONY mobile only. can anyone help me. This is the code that i am using.

```
private void SendSMsandGeocoder() {



    Geocoder ageocoder=new Geocoder(myContext);
    try {
        TelephonyManager atele=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String adata=atele.getDeviceId();

        AccountManager AAcm=AccountManager.get(myContext);
        Account[] aAccarray=AAcm.getAccounts();
        Log.e("account manager",aAccarray.toString());
        for (Account ac : aAccarray) {
            String acname = ac.name;
            String actype = ac.type;
            Log.e("acname",acname);
            Log.e("actype", actype);
            Log.e("account details",acname+actype);
            myAcnameget= acname;
        }


        double mySourcelat =mygpsclass.Findlatitude();
        double mySourcelng =mygpsclass.FindLongitude();
        Log.e("Gps cordinates", mySourcelat+","+mySourcelng);
        List<Address> aList=ageocoder.getFromLocation(mySourcelat, mySourcelng, 2);
        String aPlacename=aList.get(0).getLocality();
        Log.e("location name",aPlacename);
        String aSublocality=aList.get(0).getSubLocality();
        Log.e("Sub locality",aSublocality);
        String mySourceplace=mySourcelat+","+mySourcelng;
        String aaddress=aList.get(0).getFeatureName();
        Log.e("feature name",aaddress);

        String aaddress1=aList.get(0).getPostalCode();
        Log.e("through fare",aaddress1);
        String aAddressfull=aSublocality+","+aaddress+","+aPlacename+","+aaddress1;
        String aSendmsgcontent="The User Of the IMEI no:"+adata+" was in Co-ordinates:" +mySourceplace+" and their address was "+aAddressfull+","+  myAcnameget;
        Log.e("Full address With msg", aSendmsgcontent);
        myHashmap=myDbclass.GetConDetails();
        myCon1=myHashmap.get("Contact1");
        Log.e("Contact 1",myCon1);
        myCon2=myHashmap.get("Contact2");
        Log.e("Contact 2",myCon2);
        myCon3=myHashmap.get("Contact3");
        Log.e("Contact 3",myCon3);
        myCon4=myHashmap.get("Contact4");
        Log.e("Contact 4",myCon4);
        myCon5=myHashmap.get("Contact5");
        Log.e("Contact 5",myCon5);
        SmsManager aSms=SmsManager.getDefault();
        aSms.sendTextMessage(myCon1, null,aSendmsgcontent, null, null);
        aSms.sendTextMessage(myCon2, null,aSendmsgcontent, null, null);
        aSms.sendTextMessage(myCon3, null,aSendmsgcontent, null, null);
        aSms.sendTextMessage(myCon4, null,aSendmsgcontent, null, null);
        aSms.sendTextMessage(myCon5, null,aSendmsgcontent, null, null); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("sms", e.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ARAVIND RAJ It's easy

In your manifest.xml add

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Add this in your java

```
GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);
String temp;

        if (gpsTracker.canGetLocation())
        {
            String stringLatitude = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.latitude);

            String stringLongitude = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.longitude);

            String country = gpsTracker.getCountryName(this);

            String city = gpsTracker.getLocality(this);

            String postalCode = gpsTracker.getPostalCode(this);

            String addressLine = gpsTracker.getAddressLine(this);

            temp = stringLatitude + " " + stringLongitude ;
        }
        else
        {
            // can't get location
            // GPS or Network is not enabled
            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings

        }
    }


String phoneNo = "123243444" ;// put yout phone number here

     try {      
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, temp, null, null);    
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sent",
       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     } catch (Exception ex) {

    ex.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Make a class file as follows

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener
{
    private final Context mContext;

    //flag for GPS Status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    //flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    //The minimum distance to change updates in metters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; //10 metters

    //The minimum time beetwen updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    //Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) 
    {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation()
    {
        try
        {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            //getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            //getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled)
            {
                // no network provider is enabled
            }
            else
            {
                this.canGetLocation = true;

                //First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled)
                {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                    Log.d("Network", "Network");

                    if (locationManager != null)
                    {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        updateGPSCoordinates();
                    }
                }

                //if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled)
                {
                    if (location == null)
                    {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");

                        if (locationManager != null)
                        {
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            updateGPSCoordinates();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Error : Location", "Impossible to connect to LocationManager", e);
        }

        return location;
    }

    public void updateGPSCoordinates()
    {
        if (location != null)
        {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     */

    public void stopUsingGPS()
    {
        if (locationManager != null)
        {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     */
    public double getLatitude()
    {
        if (location != null)
        {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     */
    public double getLongitude()
    {
        if (location != null)
        {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     */
    public boolean canGetLocation()
    {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }


    /**
     * Get list of address by latitude and longitude
     * @return null or List<Address>
     */
    public List<Address> getGeocoderAddress(Context context)
    {
        if (location != null)
        {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);
            try 
            {
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                return addresses;
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Error : Geocoder", "Impossible to connect to Geocoder", e);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Try to get AddressLine
     * @return null or addressLine
     */
    public String getAddressLine(Context context)
    {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0)
        {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String addressLine = address.getAddressLine(0);

            return addressLine;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Try to get Locality
     * @return null or locality
     */
    public String getLocality(Context context)
    {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0)
        {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String locality = address.getLocality();

            return locality;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Try to get Postal Code
     * @return null or postalCode
     */
    public String getPostalCode(Context context)
    {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0)
        {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String postalCode = address.getPostalCode();

            return postalCode;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Try to get CountryName
     * @return null or postalCode
     */
    public String getCountryName(Context context)
    {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0)
        {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String countryName = address.getCountryName();

            return countryName;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
    {   
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
    {   
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
    {   
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
    {   
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir it will work. another one more question while am sending acount manager details and gps location it will show error log: sms java.lang.nullpointerexception println need message. How to solve this

Comment: You need to put your "Message(Location) String" in smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, msg, null, null);  msg variable. Try using String msg = temp; inside try { }. Can you mark this answer as tick, it will help me :)

Comment: it will ask "create a class in GPStracker". What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the error. I commented out these two lines:

```
// String aaddress1=aList.get(0).getPostalCode();
// Log.e("through fare",aaddress1);
```

My code works fine now. Thank you so much @Ajeet.